How to get letters from a folder in Cyrillic?
I want to receive all letters from a folder in Cyrillic
I tried many different functions, but I didn’t find a working method, everything is ok with other folders
$folder = "Название папки на кирилице" ;
imap_open("{imap.example.com}/".$folder, $login, $password);

i get error

Notice: Unknown: [CLIENTBUG] SELECT No such folder. sc=xQG456O15YuQ0_200927_imap-production-586 (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

I tried
imap_utf7_decode() and iconv

Have you tried calling imap_list on the server itself to confirm that it exists?

Documentation says: Mailbox names that contain international characters besides those in the printable ASCII space have to be encoded with imap_utf7_encode().
